# Java Application using Https Connection:"Connection refused error"

Tags: java, servlets, https, jar, war

I have  created a jar for my JavaAppliaction.From this application I am connecting to servlet (I am passing name and password from swing to servlet) in the WebApplicaton(here I am just displaying name and password in the servlet).

I am passing data over SSL connection(Https). It is working fine in my system.But when I tried to run jar in another system I am getting “Connection refused error”.

Note:Running jar in another system which passes data over http connection is working fine.

I have gone through this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) which  suggested me to create a “jssecacerts” file and paste it in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder of the “another system”. But I am still getting same error. Why is this not working??

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: @beny23:I have pasted the [Stacktrace](http://pastie.org/3719394)

Comment: @hage: Yeah my firewall is turned off. But the system also has all traffic redirected through a proxy. Does this will have any effect??

Comment: This is probably due to your proxy then. You should try setting the following system properties if not done so already: System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", String.valueOf(true)); System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost); System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", sProxyHost); System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(proxyPort));System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", String.valueOf(sProxyPort)); If your proxy requires authentication, then you will also need to set an `Authenticator`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: Try importing the public certificate into java default keystore using.

keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file "path-to-public-cert" -keystore JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

it will ask for keystore password default keystore password is "changeit"

You can obtain the public cert by opening your URL in a web browser (e.g chrome) click on the icon at the start of URL -> click certificate information -> details tab -> click export 
 button.

---

A better approach will be:

- create a keystore using "keytool" available in JAVA_HOME/bin
- Import your server's public cert in this keystore.
- bundle the keystore with your app.
- make a bat / sh file to run your jar providing a parameter to java command -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path-to-your-keystore

So every time your app will start it will use this custom keystore. so you don't have to copy jssecacerts file on each system your run your app on.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you are trying to help. But I am guessing that this is not the answer he is looking for. He is asking for a solution to another problem right? Also I have another query: Isn't pasting the jssacerts does the same which you are trying to automate with a script right??

Comment: yeah, I was trying to eliminate the step of copying jssacerts. Edited the post added a possible solution.

Comment: "java is not able to find the public cert to communicate with server" This is a terribly imprecise way of putting it. The error indicates that the client's truststore doesn't trust the server's keystore. Your solution is correct: your problem statement is not.

Comment: @amitp:I have created a certificate in my system using this command:keytool -export -file test.cert -keystore test -storepass 123456 -alias sriram 
Ans: Certificate stored in file <test.cert>.I have imported this certificate in cacerts of new system using the command specified above.The output is something like this:Trust this certificate? [no]: yes
Certificate was added to keystore..But still I am getting the same error when I run my jar file in new system...Where I went wrong??

Comment: You have created a separate "keystore" with name test in your keytool command. I my post I specified the path of default java keystore so the certificate is added in default keystore. But no worries when running the Jar file you can explicitly specify the path of keystore file as I already wrote in last line of orignal post.
java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<Path-to-your-keystore> <jarfile path>
You can create a batch file using above command to run your Jar. This is the way to go SHIP your keystore with your APP.