# unable to find valid certification path

Tags: java, https, war, executable-jar

I have created a certificate in my system using this command:

```
keytool -export -file test.cert -keystore test -storepass 123456 -alias sriram 
Ans: Certificate stored in file <test.cert>.
```

I have imported this certificate in cacerts of new system using the command :

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file "path-to-public-cert" -keystore JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts".

The output is something like this:Trust this certificate? [no]: yes Certificate was added to keystore.
```

But still I am getting the [link](http://pastie.org/3719394) error when I run my jar file in new system...Where I went wrong??

Comment: and have you added the certificate configurations correctly in your tomcat? can you show me the tomcat server.xml with regards to ssl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290570/pkix-path-building-failed-while-making-ssl-connection this link might help you

Comment: [link](http://pastie.org/3755116)..This is in my system(server)

Comment: @linuxeasy:you may go through this [basic problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989340/java-application-using-https-connectionconnection-refused-error)..so that you may get better idea of my problem...

Comment: [link](http://pastie.org/3755134) try matching up with the config, Even I was going thru the same errors. Also try to follow [these](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Demo) steps, uptil certification creation and apache config, ignore CAS stuffs. May be it will help you

Comment: The server.xml you specified should be on the server side??

Comment: yes, this should be on server side

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the Apache Tomcat [SSL Configuration How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

In [Edit the Tomcat Configuration File](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) paragraph it explain that you can had the `keystoreFile` attribute to the connector configuration.

```
<Connector 
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```